# Prove that these two conditions are equivalent

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that these two conditions are equivalent:

1. $m, n$ are coprime;
2. for any group $G$, for any subgroup $A \subseteq G$ of order $m$ and for any subgroup $B \subseteq G$ of order $n$ we have $A \cap B = \{e\}$.

My only guess is that in $2 \rightarrow 1$ case we should go from the opposite and show that $\gcd(m, n) > 1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that $m$ and $n$ are coprime. If $G$ is a group, if $A$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $m$, and if $B$ is a subgroup of $G$ with order $n$, let $g\in A\cap B$. Then the order of $g$ divides both $m$ and $n$ and therefore it is equal to $1$. So, $g=e$.

If $m$ and $n$ are *not* coprime, just think about $\mathbb Z_{mn}$.

Comment: So I can take $G = Z_{mn}, A = Z_{m}, B = Z_{n}$. And then $A \cap B = Z_{min(m, n)}$, but min(m, n) > 1 and therefore $A \cap B \neq Z_{1} = \{e\}$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, and shouldn't here be $gcd(m, n)$ instead of $min(m,n)$?

Comment: @James Yes, that is correct.